# Angular ui-bootstrap modal unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have read a lot of questions about this problem but I'm still not able to find a solution for my case.

```
Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal
```

What I have done so far:

installed `angular-bootstrap` via npm

```
npm install angular-bootstrap
```

added `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` in my index.html after `angular.js` and `angular-route.js` and before `app.js` and controllers

added this code in app.js

```
var angularApp= angular.module('angularApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);

var confirmPopup = null;
angularApp.run(function ($rootScope, $http, $location, $interval, authService, $uibModal, $timeout, $route) {


    alert = function (text) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/partials/alertmodal.html',
            controller: 'alertController',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                text: function () {
                    return text;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    confirmPopup = function (text, callBacktrue, callBackfalse) {
        var confirmbool;

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/partials/modal.html',
            controller: 'modalController',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                text: function () {
                    return text;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(callBacktrue, callBackfalse);
    };
});
```

(there is some more code in this part but it isn't relevant at this moment)

I called so far nowhere the modal or alert function, so isn't used so far.

What I'm doing wrong? I'm still pretty new with angular, so if it is possible I like a detailed explanation with some examples.

Thanks!

Comment: did you inject angular-ui into your main module?

Comment: You should inject `ui.bootstrap` in your app module..

Comment: Excuses, forget that code, yes, I inject that (code added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have included the angular ui file script in your page ?

If yes, it should work. If not, maybe you should gice us a jsfiddle (or other site) sample

Comment: This should have been a comment !

Comment: I have putted it as answer cause I guess he forgot to include the file.

Comment: It was a partial solution. I didn't have a angular-ui.js file so after a few searched I find angular-ui-bootstrap instead of angular-bootstrap. (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) so after installing that via npm and including the two files, everything is running!